# Making Social Icons change color on hover when using pseudo element contents

Tags: css, html

I've got a series of social icons that are rendered using an icon font and the css `content:` property.

```
.icon-google-plus:before {
    content: "\e003";
}
```

displays the google plus icon in a pseudo before element.

How can I make this icon change color on hover ? I thought, wrongly it would be something similar to this...

```
.icon-google-plus:before a:hover {
    colour: @google_plus_red;
}
```

My markup as requested

```
<a class="share_styx icon-google-plus" target="_blank" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={{url absolute="true"}}">
 <span class="hidethis_styx">
    Google+
 </span>
</a>
```

Comment: please include your HTML markup, the order of your selectors is wrong, should look more like `a:hover .icon-google-plus:before`

Comment: I've tried that. No Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 a.icon-google-plus:hover:before {
    color: red;
}
```

it will change the icon's color on hovering the link.

Comment: Can you explain how you knew which order the pseudo elements should have been in. e.g. why is it `:hover:before`?

Comment: @Luke Because the :hover event is happening to the anchor tag (`a`), not the pseudo element. Also the class is applied to the anchor tag, not the pseudo element. Hence, :before comes last